# Couple of errors

Tags: java

When I call this code in Terminal on my Mac it tells me "could not find or load main class" also it gives me a lot of errors on all of my code regarding printf.

I am new to Java so I assume this code is error ridden.

All I am really asking is how to fix it so it will run in terminal when I type "java itemprice" for it to not show an error.

Also I would like some help with the system.out.printf code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class itempricecalc {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is your first name?");
    String fname = scanner.nextLine();
    String invf = fname.substring(0,2);

    System.out.print("What is your last name?");
    String lname = scanner.nextLine();
    String invl = lname.substring(0,2);

    System.out.println("Your name is: " +fname + lname);



    System.out.println("What is your zipcode?");
    int zipcode = scanner.nextInt();

    invoice = (invf + invl + zipcode);

    double salestax = 6.25;

    double subtotal = 0;

    System.out.println("What is item 1 called?")
    String itemonename = scanner.nextLine():

    System.out.println("Enter price of item 1");
    double itemone = scanner.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("How many of item 1 did you purchase?");
    int itemoneamount = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("What is item 2 called?")
    String itemtwoname = scanner.nextLine():

    System.out.println("Enter price of item 2");
    double itemtwo = scanner.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("How many of item 2 did you purchase?");
    int itemtwoamount = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("What is item 3 called?")
    String itemthreename = scanner.nextLine():

    System.out.println("Enter price of item 3");
    double itemthree = scanner.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("How many of item 3 did you purchase?");
    int itemthreeamount = scanner.nextInt();

    double itemonetp = itemoneamount * itemone;
    double itemtwotp = itemtwoamount * itemtwo;

    double totalprice = itemonetp + itemtwotp;

    subtotal = subtotal + totalprice;

    double taxtotal = subtotal * salestax;

    System.out.print("Your name is: " + fname + " " + lname)
    System.out.printf(“Invoice: %.2f”, invoice);
    System.out.printf(“Total price of item one is + %.2f”, itemonetp);
    System.out.printf(“Total price of item two is + %.2f”, itemtwotp);
    System.out.printf(“Total price of your purchase is + %.2f”, totalprice);
    System.out.printf(“Your total with tax comes to + %.2f”, taxtotal);
    System.out.printf(“You purchased + %.2f + amount of item one”, itemoneamount);
    System.out.printf(“You purchased + %.2f + amount of item two”, itemtwoamount);



}       

}
```

Comment: First, fix the compilation errors in printf... which are? I see a missing semicolon on the `print` call before you have `printf`.

Comment: system.out.printf is a method you can use i think

Comment: @OwenHartman: yes you can, but your question is about compilation errors and yet you don't show them. If it's about the printf statement, then likely your IDE needs to have its Java compliance level changed to Java 1.8. If Eclipse then Google Eclipse Java compiler compliance level.

Comment: You should replace those creepy quotes (`“` and `”`) with the normal ones (`"`). Also, variable `invoice` is not declared. Third, you need to install an IDE. Fourth, you need to stick to the Java Naming Convention, `itempricecalc` should start with an uppercase letter.